# how to work with data from another controller in modal window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-strap

I have a question about how can I get data from a controller and put it into a scope of another controller which is modal window...

I will explain:

here is my event, which opens dialog window (angular-strap modal):

```
openDialog () {
    this.$modal({
        show: true,
        html: true,
        placement: 'center',
        type: 'large',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
        controller: myController
    });
}
```

this is my modal window template (tmpl.html):

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

as I use webpack, I initialize a module with my directive in main index.js

here is a small example of my template of a directive:

```
<span class="some-name">{{$ctrl.num}} </span>
```

here is my another controller:

```
constructor($scope) {
    super($scope);

    this.$scope = $scope;

    this.num = 10;
}
```

So, as you can see there will be 10 in the span, I also need to get data from another controller, which stores i.e. data = ['asd', 'apple']; and so on

is there a better to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pass scope from the parent controller to the modal by adding scope to your modal options. See below:

```
 this.$modal({
        show: true,
        html: true,
        placement: 'center',
        type: 'large',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
        controller: myController,
        scope: $scope
    });
```

Is that all that you're asking?

Comment: sure, I've tried that, but that didn't help at all =(

Comment: is <span class="some-name">{{$ctrl.num}} </span> showing 10? I couldn't tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resolve` property from `modal`

openDialog () {

```
    this.$modal({
        show: true,
        html: true,
        placement: 'center',
        type: 'large',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
        controller: myController,
        resolve : {
          objData{
             dataFromCtrl : $scope.dataFromAnoterCtrl// you can fetch data here either from parent scope or factory/service.
        }
       }

    });
}
```

And then in `myController` , you can get the this data

```
.controller('myController',function(objData){
    console.log(objData.dataFromCtrl); // you can get data from another controller in this modal controller.
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I need to update this data, because it's loaded from the server with some time interval (because data is can be updated any time)... And this will update it only when the window is opened again